# Consulta funcion max en vector python

Tags: python, array

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en donde se me pide extraer el mayor promedio de una serie N de datos que almaceno en un vector. Para esto estaba usando la funcion max que me sirvio para un ejercicio pero para otro no, y les consulto que puede ser lo que este mal. Por ejemplo:

```
 vector=[['10.0', '12.0', '11.3', '7.5', '12.3', '12.5', '13.2'], ['17.0', '12.3', '14.1', '15.5', '11.0', '10.0', '15.3'], ['11.0', '16.0', '13.3', '9.5', '12.6', '12.4', '13.4'], ['10.3', '10.0', '12.3', '11.5', '11.3', '15.5', '17.1'], ['10.1', '12.0', '11.3', '6.5', '12.3', '16.5', '15.2']]
```

del cual al aplicar la funcion max:

```
print(max(vector)
```

obtengo lo siguiente:
['17.0', '12.3', '14.1', '15.5', '11.0', '10.0', '15.3']

y al aplicar min obtengo

```
El minimo es ['10.0', '12.0', '11.3', '7.5', '12.3', '12.5', '13.2']
```

En este caso el ejercicio me da bien, sin embargo, al hacer la prueba con menos datos almacenados en el vector veo que es distinto el resultado y no tiene sentido (al menos para el promedio que busco), por ejemplo:

```
[['10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10'], ['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5'], ['8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8']]

El maximo es ['8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8']
El minimo es ['10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10']
```

Hay alguna parte de la funcion **max** y **min** que no estoy entendiendo que esta haciendo que los resultados no sean los esperados. Hay alguna forma en que puedo obtener el resultado maximo y minimo verificando el promedio de todo el vector?

EDITO:

Estuve validando que con la funcion **max** sigo teniendo errores, ya que el vector que me trae no es el que cuyo resultado suma mas en la lista, por ello use otra funcion que suma los valores y ahi si me arroja el resultado:

```
def maximumSum(list1):
    maxi = 0
    for x in list1:
        sum = 0 
        for y in x:
            sum+= y     
        maxi = max(sum, maxi)  
        print(maxi)      
    return maxi
```

El problema que tengo ahora es que asi como esta el codigo me sirve parcialmente, ya que si bien obtengo el resultado correcto de los numeros, en cada vector hay un identificador previo que tengo que rescatar por ejemplo:

```
vector=[[*'3'*,'10.0', '12.0', '11.3', '7.5', '12.3', '12.5', '13.2'], ['3','17.0', '12.3', '14.1', '15.5', '11.0', '10.0', '15.3'], ['3','11.0', '16.0', '13.3', '9.5', '12.6', '12.4', '13.4'], ['3','10.3', '10.0', '12.3', '11.5', '11.3', '15.5', '17.1'], ['3','10.1', '12.0', '11.3', '6.5', '12.3', '16.5', '15.2']]
```

Ese **3** inicial no puede ser incluido dentro del promedio general dado que es un dato que si bien viene en el mismo arreglo no debe ser tomado en cuenta como dato a la hora de sacar el promedio general ya que sirve para identificar otra cosa. Pero dado que tengo que "sacar" ese dato para poder obtener el promedio bien, luego no lo puedo recuperar. A eso le sumo que cuando hice la conversion a float del string inicial no puedo dividir los datos con [], porque ya no me toma posicion como string, sino que directamente toma el vector completo como un solo valor.

Comment: El problema son los elementos, pues al ser strings no se aplica correctamente la función `max` y `min`

Comment: hice una respuesta, espero te sirva

Comment: Si, vi la respuesta y por eso borre el comentario. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Dado que haz agregado más a tu pregunta  tendré que editar mi respuesta, en un momento lo hago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El *error* se debe a que estas utilizando la función `max()` y `min()` en un vector con valores de tipo string. Lo correcto seria convertir cada lista del vector a `int` o `float`, para esto tendremos que recorrer el vector, para ello utilizaremos una comprensión de lista para hacer mas simple el proceso.

La función `max()` y `min()` al ser aplicadas a un vetor solo toma como referencia el primer elemento de todas las listas para calcular el máximo o mínimo, en caso sea igual pasara al siguiente elemento.

**solución al primer problema**

```py
vector =[['10.0', '12.0', '11.3', '17.5', '12.3', '12.5', '13.2'], ['17.0', '12.3', '14.1', '15.5', '11.0', '10.0', '15.3'], ['11.0', '16.0', '13.3', '9.5', '12.6', '12.4', '13.4'], ['10.3', '10.0', '12.3', '11.5', '11.3', '15.5', '17.1'], ['10.1', '12.0', '11.3', '6.5', '12.3', '16.5', '15.2']]

#recorremos el vector y luego convertimos a float cada valor
vector = [[float(i) for i in x] for x in vector]

print(max(vector))
print(min(vector))
```

**resultado**

```
[17.0, 12.3, 14.1, 15.5, 11.0, 10.0, 15.3]
[10.0, 12.0, 11.3, 7.5, 12.3, 12.5, 13.2]
```

Y lo mismo seria para tu otro vector

```py
vec=[['10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10'], ['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5'], ['8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8']]

vec = [[int(i) for i in x] for x in vec]

print(f"El minimo es {min(vec)}")
print(f"El maximo es {max(vec)}")
```

**resultado**

```
El minimo es [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
El maximo es [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

**solución al segundo problema**

Como dije antes, las funciones `max()` y `min()` solo toma como referencia al primer elemento, por lo que al aplicar tu función `maximumSum()` te devuelve el resultado que esperas, pero esa función se puede simplificar a 1 linea utilizando generadores, que es lo mismo que una comprensión de lista sólo que no crea una lista.

```py
maximun = max(sum(lista) for lista in vector)
```

Lo que hace el código es sumar todos los valores de cada lista del vector y luego aplica la función `max()` lo que devuelve un resultado. Obviamente primero deberás convertir la lista de stribgs a números de la forma en que te mostré en la solución al primer problema. Bueno pero lo que quieres es *omitir* al primer elemento, en ese caso se puede usar la notacion de sílice para solo coger una porción de cada lista, quedando asi:

```py
vector = [[float(i) for i in x] for x in vector]#convertimos a flotante cada valor 

#sacamos el maximo
maximun = max(sum(lista[1:]) for lista in vector)
```

Con `lista[1:]` estamos indicando que solo queremos los datos desde la posición 1 (que sería el segundo valor) hasta el final.

Comment: Disculpa hay algo que aun no entiendo y te consulto, con la notacion [1:] entiendo que omite el primer numero de la lista que previamente he convertido a string con el **vector**, y entiendo que la segunda parte hace un for para recorrer toda la lista y sacar el **max**, sin embargo la variable maximun al reemplazar los valores por el nombre **vector** me indica lo siguiente: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list' , y la linea entiendo yo queda asi:
maximun = max(sum(vector[1:]) for x in vector)

Comment: jejeje, perdon me equivoque, es correcto lo que dices, se tiene que iterar en la variable `vector` que ya esta con los valores convertidos

Comment: Si, pero eso es justamente lo que pasa, que cuando cambio los valores de la variable por la lista me indica que no se puede sumar list con un int, se que es un error de concepto de mi parte y por eso pregunto.

Comment: si recorremos el vector obtendremos cada una de esa lista y para solo operar con ciertos numero usamos el slice, la que dice el codigo es lo siguiente *suma todos los elementos de la variable lista empezando desde el segundo para cada lista en el vector*